# Reputable source for Mark Pilgrim's "Dive into Greasemonkey"

Tags: documentation, greasemonkey

Given that [Mark Pilgrim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Pilgrim_%28software_developer%29) pulled his "[Dive into Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey#External_links)" on 2011-10-06, what is a reputable source for it?

I don't want to go to a malware infested website to get it. For instance, is www.freetechbooks.com reputable?

Comment: I found the pdf at the top of the google search. No visits to sites just the pdf. Was that not good enough?

Comment: @Preet Sangha: no, a PDF file could very well be crafted to exploit known or unknown vulnerabilities in PDF readers (such as [Adobe Acrobat Reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Acrobat) (shudder) or even [Foxit Reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foxit_Reader)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The internet archive (Wayback Machine) still has it.  Here is [the last recorded snapshot, from July 26, 2011](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726001221/http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/).

Note that that book was last updated in 2005 and is extremely out of date.  The site itself says (said) this:

> This book is badly out of date and will probably never be updated. You can find more up-to-date information on [the Greasemonkey wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/).